# waiting ajax success end before going through next iteration

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a for cycle that iterates over an associative array. foreach entry i have to make an ajax request and fill another array with retrieved data.
The problem is that the success callback is asynchronous so it runs only after the cycle has been iterated. this means that my data array is filled with multiple copies of the last ajax request result.
This is my code (simplified):

```
var channels = {  
    "misured": "channel_misured",  
    "plan": "channel_plan"  
};
var data;  //Initial data is empty

function getData() {
    data = new Array();

    for (var seriesData in channels) {
        var currentData = new Array();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://' + serverAddress + ':' + serverPort + '/GetChannelBufferAsJsonp?channelName=' + channels[seriesData] + '&callback=?',
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (json) {
                var time = new Date().getTime() + 3600000;
                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    currentData.push({
                        x: time + i * 30000,
                        y: json[i]
                    });
                }

                data.push({
                    id: seriesData,
                    name: "Production " + seriesData,
                    data: currentData
                });

            }, error: function () {
                console.log("error", this);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So data has 2 elements (correct) but both of them comes from "plan_channel" (that is my data source).
I know this is a classic, well know "problem" (or feature) of ajax requests but i cannot see how i can get rid of it.
Can you tell how to wait for the success callback to end before going to the next iteration?

Comment: If i understand your question, why not use a global flag / boolean to control when your ajax request is initiated?

Comment: instead of pushing the data into the array why not clear the array with the new data?

Comment: @FiveTools Can you show how you would use a global flag in conjuction with a for loop? I cannot see it.

Comment: @ThomasClayson no, async doesn't seem to work. I already set it as you can see from the code.

Comment: @Eli that would not change anything. And please use answers instead of comment. this is how stackoverflow works. I will not downvote any answer so no worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way (off the top of my head) I can see to refactor your code. Its a bit pointless though. You've got your set up all wrong IMO, you shouldn't be doing it that way. The best way I can see to do it would be to send the whole array in one ajax request to the ajax script, deal with it all in the php (or whatever) and spit it back out in the format you want it in the javascript. Otherwise you'd be better off finding a better way to do this. For instance instead of having a for loop you could have an ajax request which calls back to the `getData()` function in the success call.

```
// add a global var...
var inLoop;
function getData() {
    data = new Array();

    for (var seriesData in channels) {
        inLoop = true; // set to true
        var currentData = new Array();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://' + serverAddress + ':' + serverPort + '/GetChannelBufferAsJsonp?channelName=' + channels[seriesData] + '&callback=?',
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (json) {
                // set inLoop to false to get out of loop below
                inLoop = false;
                var time = new Date().getTime() + 3600000;
                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    currentData.push({
                        x: time + i * 30000,
                        y: json[i]
                    });
                }

                data.push({
                    id: seriesData,
                    name: "Production " + seriesData,
                    data: currentData
                });

            }, error: function () {
                console.log("error", this);
            }
        });

        // loop round this bit for a while
        while(inLoop){
          // wait
        }
    }


}
```

This is how I would rewrite the code above:

```
var channels = {
  "first" : "hello world",
  "second" : "goodbye world"
}

function getData(channel){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://whatever.com/channel='+channel,
    success: function(){
      getData(nextchannel);
    }
  });
}
```

In order to do this you might have to count the times you go through the function or something in order to be able to pass the next channel into the function again.

Comment: but if you have a while that polls the variable doesn't the browser say "there's a script thats not responding?"

Comment: Well, i know how to handle ajax requests in general but in this particular scenario i cannot change the way my "server" answers as i have big hardware bounds in field sensors.  Anyway your solution doesn't seem to work as the while loop never ends (the inLoop variable is always true

Comment: @EvilP hmm thats quite possible. Its silly anyway, just stalling the script with a while loop. Its better to completely rewrite that code. @andreapier the inLoop var is set to false in the success function. But its not a good way to write code. I would suggest rewriting and sending a new request to `getData` from the success function of the ajax request, rather than using a for loop.

Comment: so If you use .getData() you have a success function that is called when the ajax request is done and "successful" ?

Comment: Your edit opened my mind, thanks. I was hardly bad, This is a great solution and quite generalizable too!

Answer (score 1):

For synchronous AJAX calls you can't use the success handler and must return results once your call has completed.

Trying using Amplify.js(http://amplifyjs.com/) with the asyc set to false; It's quite easy to use and neater than the jQuery ajax function. Don't be put off by the additional library.

Update #1

You simply have to do this

```
function getData() {
    data = new Array();

    for (var seriesData in channels) {
        var currentData = new Array();


    amplify.request.define( "ajaxExample1", "ajax", {
        url: 'http://' + serverAddress + ':' + serverPort + '/GetChannelBufferAsJsonp?channelName=' + channels[seriesData] + '&callback=?',
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        type: "GET"
    });

    // later in code
    amplify.request( "ajaxExample1", function( json ) {
        var time = new Date().getTime() + 3600000;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            currentData.push({
                x: time + i * 30000,
                y: json[i]
            });
        }

        data.push({
            id: seriesData,
            name: "Production " + seriesData,
            data: currentData
        });
    });

    }
}
```